# Loop Instead of Button for displaying images in JLabel?

Tags: java, image, swing, loops

How can I automatically run Images of a directory continuously on a JLabel without the use of a Button (Pressed to skip to the next image).
I want to get an image on a jlabel.
Pls Help!

use of timer could be one option but how can I implement it?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ShowLabelImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ShowLabelImage();
    }

    private JLabel label;

    private List<BufferedImage> images;
    private int currentPic = 0;

    public ShowLabelImage() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                images = new ArrayList<>(2);
                try {
                    images.add(ImageIO.read(new File("path/to/pic1")));
                    images.add(ImageIO.read(new File("path/to/pic2")));
                } catch (IOException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }

                label = new JLabel();
                label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

                JButton switchPic = new JButton("Switch");
                switchPic.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        currentPic++;
                        if (currentPic >= images.size()) {
                            currentPic = 0;
                        }
                        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(images.get(currentPic)));
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(label);
                frame.add(switchPic, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                switchPic.doClick();
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Would u like a link or an example on how to use the timer?

Comment: *"use of timer could be one option"* If you're referring to a Swing `Timer` then I'd list that as a 'preferred option'.  *"..but how can I implement it?"* But what have you tried? SO is not a 'finish my code' service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is best answered by working through [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) in the tutorial.

Comment: Many many duplicate questions can be found: [Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=swap+images++jlabel+loop+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F)

Comment: You pretty much have it implemented already yourself. [SwingTimers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) take `ActionListeners` so you can use the one you have. All you really gotta do is create the timer, give it a delay, add the `ActionListener` and tell it to repeat itself